# Added a Column to a table but linked chart does not update with new column data

Tags: vba, excel, charts

i'm new here and i havent been able to find an answer to this.

I have a yearly store takings workbook that allows me to track sales and other monthly/yearly figures from entered takings/transaction figures.

I have some VBA code that creates a new worksheet for a new year.
The code also adds the new years figures to the relevant tables but the charts linked to these tables do not update with the new data.

first time I ran this code it worked for all tables and charts. now it occasionally works for some but not all, and not always the same ones and more often than not it doesn't update any charts at all.

My code is;

```
Dim NewPageName As String

Sub NewPage()

    Dim sName As String
    Dim wks As Worksheet

    'Unhides Master sheet

    Sheets("MASTER").Visible = True

    'Copies Master sheet & places copy after Graphs sheet

    Sheets("MASTER").Copy after:=Worksheets("Average Daily Till Diff")

    'Generates input box to name the new Sheet and checks duplicate names

    Set wks = ActiveSheet
    Do While sName <> wks.Name
        sName = Application.InputBox _
          (Prompt:="Enter New Year")
        On Error Resume Next
        wks.Name = sName
        On Error GoTo 0
    Loop
    Set wks = Nothing

    'Moves the data tables from new sheet to next empty column on to relavent data/graph sheets

    ActiveSheet.Range("D106:D107").Cut (Sheets("Total Yearly Takings").Range("IV1").End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1))
    Application.CutCopyMode = True
    Worksheets("Total Yearly Takings").Columns.AutoFit

    ActiveSheet.Range("D41:D53").Cut (Sheets("Total Monthly Takings").Range("IV1").End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1))
    Application.CutCopyMode = True
    Worksheets("Total Monthly Takings").Columns.AutoFit

    ActiveSheet.Range("D54:D66").Cut (Sheets("Average Daily Takings").Range("IV1").End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1))
    Application.CutCopyMode = True
    Worksheets("Average Daily Takings").Columns.AutoFit

    ActiveSheet.Range("D93:D105").Cut (Sheets("Average Daily Basket").Range("IV1").End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1))
    Application.CutCopyMode = True
    Worksheets("Average Daily Basket").Columns.AutoFit

    ActiveSheet.Range("D108:D109").Cut (Sheets("Total Yearly Till Diff").Range("IV1").End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1))
    Application.CutCopyMode = True
    Worksheets("Total Yearly Till Diff").Columns.AutoFit

    ActiveSheet.Range("D67:D79").Cut (Sheets("Total Monthly Till Diff").Range("IV1").End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1))
    Application.CutCopyMode = True
    Worksheets("Total Monthly Till Diff").Columns.AutoFit

    ActiveSheet.Range("D80:D92").Cut (Sheets("Average Monthly Till Diff").Range("IV1").End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1))
    Application.CutCopyMode = True
    Worksheets("Average Monthly Till Diff").Columns.AutoFit

    ActiveSheet.Range("D110:D111").Cut (Sheets("Average Daily Till Diff").Range("IV1").End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1))
    Application.CutCopyMode = True
    Worksheets("Average Daily Till Diff").Columns.AutoFit

    'Hides the Master sheet

    Sheets("MASTER").Visible = False

End Sub
```

Anyone able to help?

Comment: Are the new columns included in the chart source?

Comment: Chart source is an existing table, new columns are cut as standard cells from the new worksheet, when these are pasted to destination the table recognises them as a new column in that table but the charts do not update to include this new column. when manually checking the chart source afterwards the new column is not included.

Comment: After a little more testing, the charts do update with the new columns data if i have had the worksheet that the table and chart are on as an active worksheet since the last time the workbook was opened and before i add the new years sheet. Is there a way to cycle through all the chart worksheets as an auto macro when the workbook opens?

Comment: Yes - in the "ThisWorkbook" object add a `Workbook_Open` sub.  `Dim` a `Chart` object, then use a `For Each` loop to go though every `Chart` in the `ThisWorkbook.Charts` collection and `.Activate` them.  To run through all Charts *and* Worksheets, `Dim` an `Object`, and go through the `ThisWorkbook.Sheets` collection instead.  (`ThisWorkbook.Sheets` contains all `ThisWorkbook.Charts` **and** `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets`)

Comment: Thank you. That's done it :)

Answer (score 0):

This was sorted by adding;

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

'Activate a Sheet
   Sheets("Average Daily Till Diff").Activate
   Sheets("Average Monthly Till Diff").Activate
   Sheets("Total Monthly Till Diff").Activate
   Sheets("Total Yearly Till Diff").Activate
   Sheets("Average Daily Basket").Activate
   Sheets("Average Daily Takings").Activate
   Sheets("Total Monthly Takings").Activate
   Sheets("Total Yearly Takings").Activate

End Sub
```

This made the workbook cycle through all the worksheets that contain a chart when opened and allowed the original code to add a new sheet and add that sheets data to the tables and the charts. Thank you all for your help.